# How can I restrict a column to have only a fixed number of duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Lets say I have a table **tblPerson** with below values. And In **Name** field I don't want the names to get repeated more than 2 times.

```
ID  Name
1   JOHN HONAY
2   PETER CAM
3   JOHN HONAY
```

So If I try to insert a new row in **tblPerson** with Name as "**JOHN HONAY**". It should throw error. How can I achieve this. Can I do something during the creation of table itself?

Comment: There is a truly [**ugly** way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510713/enforce-maximum-number-of-child-rows) but I'd generally advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

I think of

- On insert/ on update Triggers to check how many times the value is exists in database
- Make your BL (Business logic) check for the duplicate

Comment: Don't forget to include an `update` trigger to handle duplicates created as a result of name changes.